# VS CODE autocomenta php

Tags: php, html5, vscode

descargue VScode y lo estoy configurando, el caso es que el código php no se ejecuta dentro de las etiquetas html, fui al navegador a verificar que pasa, le di inspeccionar y me encontré que el código php no se ejecuta por que esta comentado, lo cual, yo no hice esa acción, he estado buscando en foro y no encuentro nada, no omito mencionar que instale live server y su extencion, no se que pueda estar ocasionando este problema.

Comment: Usa XAMP y editas los archivos con VS Code

Comment: si efectivamente eso hago!

Comment: ¿tienes los servicios funcionando?

Comment: si! tengo los servicios funcionando..

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega tu código HTML junto con el PHP que trae dentro.